# копирвать символы из Value google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите. Есть данные в ячейке таблицы
.getRange('A1').getValue() // Например test12

Как мне скопировать символы 12 (ну или не 12, а например, символы под порядковыми номерами начиная с нулевого четвертый и пятый). И поместить их в B1

Comment: `substring(4, 5)` - оно?

Answer (score 0):

Получите данные, измените, запишите в нужное место

```
var value = sheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
var newValue = value.substring(4, 6);
sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(newValue);
```